# Raspbian: mount: / is busy (tried to remount sd card as read only)

Tags: raspbian, mount, readwrite

Due to an sd card corruption I decided to mount the root fs as read only. Therefore, I added the 'ro' argument in /etc/fstab

```
/dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot           vfat    defaults,ro          0       2
/dev/mmcblk0p2  /               ext4    defaults,ro,noatime  0       1
```

After the device is booted, the filesystem is mounted read-only - so that's fine. However, sometimes I need write access to the file system. So, I remount the root fs with

`sudo mount / -o remount,rw`

as read/write. However, if I want to remount the filesystem with

`sudo mount / -o remount,ro`

I get the following error:

`mount: / is busy`

If I run:

`fuser -v ./`

I get the following output:

```
USER PID ACCESS COMMAND
pi   2421 ..c.. sftp-server
pi   2477 ..c.. bash
```

Does anybody know what's causing the problem? Why can the filesystem be mounted as read only at startup, but not if I remount it manually?

Comment: Have you solved your problem? If so, please mark the answer that helped you, or if you solved it on your own, create a self-answer and mark it as such. We are trying to get the site Q:A ratio up and marking answers is what does that. If you resolved it and mark then people in the future will be able to profit from what you did *and* it helps move the site closer to graduation. Thanks!

Comment: Same problem here. What's more, sometimes remount,ro succeeds, sometime is shows "/ is busy".

Answer (score 3):

You can emulate a magic sysrq keypress by executing

```
# echo "u" > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

This causes the kernel to low-level try to remount all filesystems read only, see [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysrq.html).

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely because something (by the looks of that command it is the BASH shell and SFTP-Server) is/are accessing the root filesystem. During boot nothing is accessing anything in `/` yet, so it can be set to read-only.

However, once boot-up is complete, some software may want a lock on the filesystem or some files are being changed within. Obviously, as all the files that Raspbian uses - software, personal files, logs, etc. - are within the root filesystem. Thus you get the `mount: / is busy` error.

If you were able to kill both BASH and SFTP-server and then run the command, I suspect that it would work fine. However, because BASH is the way you are entering the commands, and BASH is stored on the `/` partition, that can't happen.

Comment: If you shut off the SSH service via `/etc/init.d/ssh stop` that might be enough to make it go, even without killing bash.

Answer (score 2):

If you still can not unmount or remount your device after stopping all services and processes with open files, then there may be a swap file or swap partition keeping your device busy. This will not show up with `fuser` or `lsof`. Turn off swapping with:

```
sudo swapoff -a
```

You could check beforehand and show a summary of any swap partitions or swap files with:

```
swapon -s
```

or:

```
cat /proc/swaps
```

As an alternative to using the command `sudo swapoff -a`, you might also be able to disable the swap by stopping a service or *systemd* unit. For example:

```
sudo systemctl stop dphys-swapfile
```

or:

```
sudo systemctl stop var-swap.swap
```

In my case, turning off swap was necessary, in addition to stopping any services and processes with files open for writing, so that I could remount my root partition as read only in order to run `fsck` on my root partition without rebooting. This was necessary on a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian Jessie.

Answer (score 1):

On many SD cards, there is a switch prohibiting write access. If it is off, switch it the other way to disable write protection.

[image: Image Courtesy of jackenhack.com]

If the switch is not to blame, I would advise following the advice [here](http://hackaday.com/2013/08/19/rescuing-an-sd-card-with-an-arduino/) for rescuing.

Comment: On the raspberry pi, the write protect switch is not connected, so the position of the switch on the card does not matter.

Answer (score 1):

I was banging the same wall for a long time, until I found this: https://wiki.debian.org/ReadonlyRoot#Find_processes_blocking_the_remount_readonly

When lsof and fuser do not show any files opened for writing on / (which seems your case), there could still be processes that have opened files that were deleted since, and they are blocking the remount.

The following command shows these proceses:

`lsof +L1; lsof|sed -n '/SYSV/d; /DEL\|(path /p;' |grep -Ev '/(dev|home|tmp|var)'`

After restarting deamons shown in the list and killing the rest, `mount -o remount,ro /` went fine.

Comment: Thanks for this, an upgrade had replaced the binary for `agetty`, yet the processes were still running with the old (now deleted) binary. Your command identified the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you probably have some app writing to the filesystem... i suspect the sftp-server is transferring something.

So until the file is not write closed or killed, it's probably locking up the remount as ro

Comment: I had the same idea, but killing the sftp-server didn't change anything. 

However, after countless hours of trying I finally got it to work with IPE http://riscpi.co.uk/nutcom-services-ltd/